# Displaying Soft Keypad Via Code

Tags: java, android

How could I keep the keypad visible, or display the keypad for the next EditText views via.  I would like to keep the keypad visible if the input is invalid.  Or, in the case of valid input, display the keypad after requesting focus on the next EditText.

My validation:

```
private boolean processTextField( EditText str ) {

        Log.v( "Exfo. Processing: ", str.getText().toString() );

        boolean notZero = ( (str.getText().toString().length() > 0) &&  (this.notZero(str.getText().toString())) ); // checks id value is zero

        if ( notZero ) {
            if ( this.frameSizeLength() == 0 ) {
                txtFrameSize.requestFocus();
                // TO DO:  display keyboard
            }
            else if ( this.thruPutLength() == 0 ) {
                txtThruPut.requestFocus();
                // TO DO:  display keyboard
            }
            else
                    this.calcResults(Integer.valueOf(txtFrameSize.getText().toString()), Float.valueOf(txtThruPut.getText().toString()) );
            }
            else {
                this.showMSG("Enter a value greater than zero.");
                // TO DO:  keep focus on current EditTExt, display keypad
            }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:  There are only 2 EditText views: framesize and thruput.

Right now, no matter what, the keypad is hidden after hitting the return/done button.  I am targeting Android 2.2, but I focusing on touch only devices for now.
Thanks,
MD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to force it open on a specified View.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

Comment: Not sure if implemented this right.  As a test, I placed in the validation block, but nothing happens.  Tried reading the documentation, but no help, just says will show the input method.  Aside from specifying the input for the EditText, is there something in the application settings that should flagged?

Comment: SOLVED.  Had to add a line in the event listener on the alert. @RobbyPond, thanks for setting on the right track.