# Displaying Keypad

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I have 2 EditText fields, and I would like to display the key pad for the second immediately after validation of the first one succeeds (I don't want the user to tap the second field).  I have tried the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236500/displaying-soft-keypad-via-code), but I can only get it to work when validation fails and the user taps OK on the error pop up:

```
private void showMSG( String str, final EditText txtField ) {
        
        // build pop up box with error message
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( this );
        builder.setMessage( str )
                .setTitle( "Input Error" )
                .setCancelable( false )
                .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { 
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        showKeyPad( txtField );
                        //((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(txtField, 0);
                    }
                });
        
        
        AlertDialog message = builder.create();
        message.show();
    } // END showMSG() -----
```

The keypad does not display if validation passes and the second field still needs input:

```
if ( this.frameSizeLength() == 0 ) {
                    this.txtFrameSize.requestFocus();
                    // TO DO:  display keyboard
                    this.showKeyPad( this.txtFrameSize );
}
```

I created a method to show the keypad knowing I would need to show the keypad in more than one case:

```
private void showKeyPad( View v ) {
        ( (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) ).showSoftInput(v, 0);
    } // END showKeyPad() -----
```

Everything sent to showKeyPad() is an EditText, and after reading Android docs, I'm still at a loss.

Thanks,
MD.

Comment: This seems very complicated, I have never had to manually ask the keypad to show. I would just try to pass the next field "focus", and it should pop up by it self. What are you testing this on?

Answer (score 0):

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) Main.mainClassInstance
.getSystemService(Main.mainClassInstance.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

   imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```

or

```
public void showKeyboard(View v) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) Main.mainClassInstance
            .getSystemService(Main.mainClassInstance.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(v, imm.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```